# Cosa vuol dire "scannarsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Qualche giorno fa, su RAI Radio 3 classica, ho ascoltato la musica che appare nei titoli di testa del film *Uccellacci e uccellini*, una canzone composta da Ennio Morricone" (il testo è di Pasolini?) che ho sempre trovato molto divertente. Il suo testo si può leggere su [questo sito web](http://www.chimai.com/index.cfm?module=MUS&mode=DET&id=623). La mia domanda fa riferimento a questo passaggio, che appare alla fine della canzone (grassetto mio):

> Una piccola troupe per le periferie vagabondò 
>   per campagne e paeselli **si scannò** 
>   Producendo rischiò la sua posizione 
>   Alfredo Bini 
>   dirigendo rischiò la reputazione 
>   Pier Paolo Pasolini

Non riesco a capire del tutto bene il significato di "scannarsi" nel testo sopra citato. Ho cercato questo verbo in parecchi dizionari, in particolare sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00817.jpg). Ho visto che una delle accezioni è "litigare ferocemente". Sarebbe questo il senso di "scannarsi" nel brano?

Comment: Se la risposta (per così chiamarla) è che non si può sapere del certo, allora spero i vostri voti per chiudere la domanda. Vedete la mia opinione in [questa risposta su Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1419).

Answer (score 1):

Certo, l'unica vera fonte definitiva sarebbe l'autore o qualcuno che l'ha interpellato (e, anche lì, ci sono casi di autori che – volutamente o no – danno spiegazioni fuorvianti della propria opera). Comunque, il mio orecchio da madrelingua mi suggerisce che il senso, un po' autoironico, sia proprio che nel corso della produzione del film non siano andati tutti d'amore e d'accordo (e, ovviamente, litigare ferocemente, come mandarsi a quel paese, può succedere anche fra persone che prima e poi sono e rimangono in rapporti amichevolissimi).

Le due frasi successive sulla posizione del produttore e la reputazione del regista sembrano indirettamente confermare, quasi come a dire “che gentaglia che siamo”.

Comment: Anzi, direi proprio il contrario: la troupe fece di tutto per la riuscita.

Comment: Ho visto l'altra risposta e in effetti è un'interessante interpretazione alternativa, @egreg. Entrambe sono compatibili con il resto del testo. Se volesse essere solo un elogio incondizionato della troupe, forse Pasolini (se era lui) non direbbe di aver rischiato la reputazione con un film così, e il produttore la posizione: c'è una chiara vena autoironica. Sarebbe interessante vedere se in altri testi pasoliniani “scannarsi” è usato in uno o nell'altro senso.

Comment: Pasolini sapeva che il film era “problematico” e che ci rischiava la reputazione, ma ovviamente lo riteneva un'opera valida. Vedi [qui](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uccellacci_e_uccellini#Critica)

Comment: Sono perfettamente d'accordo, @egreg. Qualcuno ha detto che secondo PPP _U. e u._ non sarebbe un'opera valida? La mia impressione è che dica “produrlo è stato un'impresa, ma eccoci qui”. Comunque non se ne esce, se non approfondendo il “lessico famigliare” di Pasolini: servirebbe un corpus dei suoi testi.

Answer (score 1):

Un'altra interpretazione potrebbe essere un'iperbole: "darsi da fare, adoperarsi con sforzi estenuanti" per onorare il proprio dovere e dedizione al proprio lavoro.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!  Questo senso corrisponderebbe all'accezione 11 del [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00817.jpg)?

Comment: Esatto proprio così! Nel caso specifico leggendo l'intero testo sia un omaggio a tutti coloro che si sono prodigati per la riuscita del film.

Comment: Il significato proposto non è nel dizionario Treccani, ma c'è nel [Sabatini-Coletti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scannare.shtml) e nel [dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/scannare.html); mi sembra quello appropriato.